Einstein's 1st postulate, Faraday's Law
I had a question about using Faraday's law as an example to explain Einstein's 1st postulate - the laws of physics are the same in all inertial reference frames.
The example given in the textbook is that when there is relative motion between a magnet and a solenoid inducing an EMF, it doesn't matter whether the magnet moves (and the solenoid is stationary), or if the solenoid moves and the magnet is stationary - as long as their relative motion is the same, the same EMF will be induced, hence Faraday's law is consistent with Einstein's 1st postulate.
The textbook used this example with the magnet/solenoid moving at a constant velocity, representing inertial reference frames. I was wondering what would happen if the magnet/solenoid was accelerating instead. Would the same EMF still be induced in both (non-inertial) reference frames? I feel like it would, but even if both reference frames generate the same EMF, can we still use it as an example to support Einstein's 1st postulate? (Since the reference frames are non-inertial now).
Many thanks in advance.

I'm not sure about the EMF induced by Faraday's law, but you certainly cannot use an accelerated reference frame to argue about Einstein's first postulate: it simply does not hold.
Einstein's first postulate refers specifically to inertial reference frames. The laws of physics look the same in all inertial reference frames. In other reference frames, new effects occur: for example centrifugal forces, the Coriolis force, gravitational effects, and so on.
In particular, I think it is worth stating that the Maxwell equations in their usual form (the one you'll find in any classical electrodynamics textbook, in terms of vector fields) do not hold in an accelerated reference frame. ]
Of course, Einstein's first postulate is "recovered" in the sense that all laws of physics are tensorial in nature, but their expressions in components can be wildly different in different reference frames.
